# probability calculation

Tags: probability

> Suppose that in class of $30$ students,there are $17$ girls and $13$ boys. Five are A students  from which three are girls. If random student is chosen, what is a probability that student is a girl or an A student.

I did not understand are A students other class? from  $30$ students, probability of girl is $17/30$, from A students, probability is $3/5$, but what about the combination of this  probabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess the A student is the highest rank student. Anyway, let A student be just some subset of these students. We know that there are 3 A girls and 2 A boys. You consider two events:
$$
E_1 = \{\text{the randomly chosen student is a girl}\}
$$
and
$$
E_2 = \{\text{the randomly chosen student is an A student}\}.
$$
So, you have to find the probability of $E_1$ *or* $E_2$, so  $\mathsf P(E_1\cup E_2)$.

Since $E_1$ and $E_2$ are not disjoint ($E_1\cap E_2 = { \text{randomly chosen student is an A girl} }$ ), you have to apply that
$$
\mathsf P(E_1 \cup E_2) = \mathsf P(E_1)+\mathsf P(E_2) -\mathsf P(E_1\cap E_2) = 1/30(17+5-3) = 19/30.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  We are told that there are five A students, of which three are girls, so two must be boys.  You have four groups:  3 A student girls, 2 A student boys, 14 non-A girls, and 11 non-A boys.  These are disjoint, so you can add probabilities.